# ReactJS- render modal component on onclick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to add ReactStrap Modal to my NavBar but couldn't find solution to it. I created a handler function which will be called upon click event but I am not able to call my login component on this handler function. I also bind the handler to the current DOM. What i have done is simply called Login component which is not working. Please explain how can I call component form this parent component

Code:
    **login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
  //  FormText,
    Label,
    Input,
    Modal,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    ModalFooter
} from 'reactstrap';

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
              <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Login</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                      <Form>
                          <FormGroup>
                              <Label for="Email">Email</Label>
                              <Input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder=""/>
                          </FormGroup>
                          <FormGroup>
                              <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                              <Input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder=""/>
                          </FormGroup>
                      </Form>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                  <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Submit</Button>{' '}
                  <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
              </Modal>
            </div>
          );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

**NavBar.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './login/login';
import {
    Navbar,
    NavbarBrand,
    NavbarToggler,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
    Collapse,
    UncontrolledDropdown,
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownItem,
    DropdownToggle
} from 'reactstrap';

class NavbarComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
**this.setState={
          isloggedOn: true
        }**

    }

    stickyNavbar() {
        var Navbar = document.getElementById("Navbar");
        console.log(Navbar);
        var sticky = Navbar.offsetTop;
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
          Navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
          Navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
      }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }

    handleClick() {
      **if(this.isloggedOn) {
    return <Login/>;
  }**
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar color="dark" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">found-Missing</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem onClick= {this.handleClick}>
                    Login
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">
                    Signup
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Reset
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
        </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default NavbarComponent;
```

Comment: You cannot call upon components to render in React, just set a state to `true` in login success and use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: i have set a state isloggedon to true and tried to call Login but it is still not working. I mean call is going to the function but not returning Component. 
Please check edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alright I have solved the issue.**

I created a state in my component and passed that state to my component along with the method(which changes the current state on  onclick event) from which component can access it from parent component.

Once the component renders modal, it will call loginmodals method of parent component and change the current state and return the current state to parent component.

Now current state is false, again Parent component will call login component with new state i.e. false on which Modal will look at the state which is false, so it will close the Modal.

**Login.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    Modal,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    ModalFooter
} from 'reactstrap';

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log(props);
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.loginmodals}>
              {/* <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button> */}
              <Modal isOpen={this.props.loginmodal} toggle={this.props.loginmodals} className={this.props.className}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.loginmodals}>Login</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                      <Form>
                          <FormGroup>
                              <Label for="Email">Email</Label>
                              <Input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder=""/>
                          </FormGroup>
                          <FormGroup>
                              <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                              <Input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder=""/>
                          </FormGroup>
                      </Form>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                  <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Submit</Button>{' '}
                  <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
              </Modal>
            </div>
          );
    }
}    
export default Login;
```

**Navbar.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './login/login';
import {
    Navbar,
    NavbarBrand,
    NavbarToggler,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
    Collapse,
    UncontrolledDropdown,
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownItem,
    DropdownToggle
} from 'reactstrap';

class NavbarComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            loginmodal: false,
            signupmodal: false
        };
        this.loginmodals = this.loginmodals.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }

    loginmodals(state) {
      this.setState({
        loginmodal: !this.state.loginmodal,
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar color="" light expand="md">
                <NavbarBrand href="/">found-Missing</NavbarBrand>
                <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                  <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLink href="/components/">About us</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">How it Works</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                      <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                        login/signup
                      </DropdownToggle>
                      <DropdownMenu right>
                        **<DropdownItem onClick={this.loginmodals}>
                          Login
                          <Login loginmodal={this.state.loginmodal} loginmodals={this.loginmodals}/>
                        </DropdownItem>**
                        <DropdownItem divider />
                        <DropdownItem>
                          Reset
                        </DropdownItem>
                      </DropdownMenu>
                    </UncontrolledDropdown>
                  </Nav>
                </Collapse>
              </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 
export default NavbarComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to trigger the modal from within NavBar, simply add a `prop` to `<NavBar />` that toggles `modal` within the state of `login.js`.

Comment: Can you please explain. I am not getting you

Comment: I see that looking over your code you are trying to render <Login /> incorrectly. You must put this inside of your render() function. Read about conditional rendering for a better understanding of how to make the component display at different times.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

- The `isLoggedOn` in your `NavBarComponent` should reside in the state. You have put it in `setState`.
- Your `handleClick` method is returning a react component. This is not right. It should just take care of toggling the state.
- As others have said, you need to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).
  With all these changes, your `NavBarComponent` should look like this:

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import Login from './login/login';
  import {
      Navbar,
      NavbarBrand,
      NavbarToggler,
      Nav,
      NavItem,
      NavLink,
      Collapse,
      UncontrolledDropdown,
      DropdownMenu,
      DropdownItem,
      DropdownToggle
  } from 'reactstrap';

  class NavbarComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
          this.state = {
              isOpen: false,
              isLoggedOn: false

          };
          this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      stickyNavbar() {
          var Navbar = document.getElementById("Navbar");
          console.log(Navbar);
          var sticky = Navbar.offsetTop;
          if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            Navbar.classList.add("sticky")
          } else {
            Navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
          }
        }

      toggle() {
          this.setState({
              isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
          });
      }

      handleClick() {
        this.setState({ isLoggedOn: true })
      }

      render() {
          return (
              <div>
                  <Navbar color="dark" light expand="md">
                      <NavbarBrand href="/">found-Missing</NavbarBrand>
                      <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                      {this.state.isLoggedOn ? <div>User successfully logged in!!</div> : (
                          <DropdownMenu right>
                              <DropdownItem onClick= {this.handleClick}>
                                  Login
                              </DropdownItem>
                              <DropdownItem href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">
                                  Signup
                              </DropdownItem>
                              <DropdownItem divider />
                              <DropdownItem>
                                  Reset
                              </DropdownItem>
                          </DropdownMenu>
                      )}
                  </Navbar>
              </div>
          )
      }
  } 

  export default NavbarComponent;
  ```

Comment: Above code still not working. Also one Question what is the use of conditional rendering when you'r not even calling login component. My point is at one point we might have to call Login component.

Comment: The `this.state.isLoggedOn...` line in the render function is meant as an example of conditional rendering.
As for your `Login` component, I can see that it is a button and you'll open a modal when the user taps it. You can use that component in the `DropdownItem`. (I'm not familiar with reactstrap but, I'm assuming that you can pass react components as children to `DropdownItem`)